# How to wait for an asynchronization method in silverlight

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, silverlight

I have made two functions in a WCF service and call them in silverlight using asynchronization. I call one method after the other, but before completion of the first method, silverlight executes the second method. I want the first method to completely finish executing before the second method call. 
thanks for your reply i m pasting my code please suggest in code how i implement.

```
          private GDOperations.GDDoneOperationsClient _gdDoneOperation;
           private ImageOperationsClient proxy = null;
           foreach (var file in _filesCollection)
           {
            clsImageTransactionEntity _clsImageEntity = new clsImageTransactionEntity();
            _clsImageEntity.ImageByte = GetFileData(file.OpenRead());
            _clsImageEntity.ImageExtension = file.Extension;
            _clsImageEntity.ImageName = file.Name;
            _clsImageEntity.ImageType = 2;
            _clsImageEntity.ImagePath = "~/CMSImages/FinalImages/" + lblSelectedBarcode.Content.ToString() + "/" + file.Name;
            _clsImageEntity.JabongBarcode = lblSelectedBarcode.Content.ToString();


            GDOperations.clsImageTransactionEntity _clsImageGDEntity = new GDOperations.clsImageTransactionEntity();
            _clsImageGDEntity.ImageExtension = file.Extension;
            _clsImageGDEntity.ImageName = file.Name;
            _clsImageGDEntity.ImageType = 2;
            _clsImageGDEntity.ImagePath = "~/CMSImages/FinalImages/" + lblSelectedBarcode.Content.ToString() + "/" + file.Name;
            _clsImageGDEntity.JabongBarcode = lblSelectedBarcode.Content.ToString();
            _clsImageGDEntity.RoleId = roleID;
            _clsImageGDEntity.TaskID = taskID;
            _clsImageGDEntity.UserID = UserId;
            _clsImageGDEntity.SystemIP = systemIP;
            _clsGdAllotment.clsImageTransactionEntity.Add(_clsImageGDEntity);
            ----- first method calling-----                
           proxy.UploadFinalImageCompleted += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (e.Error == null)
                {

                }     
            };
            proxy.UploadFinalImageAsync(_clsImageEntity);
            countfile = countfile + 1;
            pbUploadFiles.Value = countfile;

        }
        _clsGdAllotment.GdID = int.Parse(lblUserID.Content.ToString());
        _clsGdAllotment.JabongBarcode = lblSelectedBarcode.Content.ToString();
        _clsGdAllotment.TaskID = taskID;
        --- after for loop completion calling second method -----
        _gdDoneOperation.InsertGDDoneInformationCompleted +=      _gdDoneOperation_InsertGDDoneInformationCompleted;
        _gdDoneOperation.InsertGDDoneInformationAsync(_clsGdAllotment);`
```

Please help its urgent.

Comment: please consider posting a bit of code and what you already tried

Answer (score 2):

If you're using [Task-Based Async Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx):

```
var task1 = CallFirstAsyncMethod();
task1.Wait(); // waiting task to finish

var task2 = CallAnotherAsyncMethod();    

// or subscribe to the task continuation to call second
// method when first operation will finished
task1.ContinueWith(t =>
  {
    // add error handling
    var task2 = CallAnotherAsyncMethod();
  });
```

If you're using [Classical Async Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963.aspx) (a.k.a. APM):

```
IAsyncResult ar1 = CallFirstAsyncMethod();
ar1.WaitHandle.Wait();
IAsyncResult ar2 = CallSecondAsyncMethod();

// or use the same technique asynchronously
CallFirstAsyncMethod(ar => // Suppose we should provide appropriate callback
 {
    // Call to appropriate EndInvoke method

    IAsyncResult ar2 = CallSecondAsyncMethod();
 }, state);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply i m pasting my code please suggest in code how i implement

Answer (score 0):

You can call the second in the callback of the first, no ?

Or is Visual Studio < 2012

You can use [AutoResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.threading.autoresetevent%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) :

```cs
MyServiceClient clientService;
AutoResetEvent autoResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
public void Execute()
{
    InvokeCompletedEventArgs data = null;
    clientService.InvokeCompleted += (e, f) =>
    {
        data = f;
        autoResetEvent.Set();
    };
    m_proxy.MyCallAync();
    autoResetEvent.WaitOne(); // Wait the set of autoResetEvent
    m_proxy.MySecondCallAync(data); // Data return by the first call
}
```

Antoine

Comment: Note, that you can't block UI thread with AutoResetEvent.WaitOne! You need to wait in background thread and use (Deployment.Current/Control).Dispatcher.BeginInvoke to use UI Thread.

Comment: Or use [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235608(v=vs.95).aspx) if Silverlight 5